# Translation of "two for one"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Is there a French expression for "killing 2 birds with 1 stone?"  I believe that in general, "2 for 1" (e.g. there is a 2 for 1 sale on t-shirts) comes from that English idiom.

Answer (score 7):

> [Faire d'une pierre deux coups](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/faire-d-une-pierre-deux-coups).

me semble correspondre.

Answer (score 1):

Oui

> Faire d'une pierre deux coups.

correspond, en relation avec l'expression proposée,"killing 2 birds with 1 stone?". 
en: correct for the expression "killing 2 birds with 1 stone?".

Mais pour ce qui est de "two for one", ce qui est la demande initiale of j-j, j'aurais plutôt dit :

But for the shortened expression "two for one", the initial OP demand, I would rather have translated to

> deux pour le prix d'un.

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional expressions that I have seen for the idea of "2 for 1":

- 1+1 offert
- Prenez en 2, payez en 1
- Un acheté, un gratuit